# web2py to check if it is a POST action

Tags: python, post, http-post, web2py

in django, I can easily test if it is post action with

```
 if request.POST:
     do whatever
```

How do I check it is a POST action in web2py

Answer (score 3):

The request method is available from:

```
request.env.request_method
```

But for this case,

```
if request.post_vars:
    #whatever
```

is probably easier

Comment: Beware that the second solution only works if POST variables were sent. An empty POST request can only be detected by checking the request_method